# Filter the TOP x most occurring between date1 and date2

Tags: vb.net

Please refer to this question: [Visual Basic, filter on most occuring in Acces Databse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129734/visual-basic-filter-on-most-occuring-in-acces-databse/38191674?noredirect=1#comment63810629_38191674)

So after a long study I have made a form and figured out on how to show the query data in my datagridview1, I made it like this (as a Private sub)

```
Private Sub FilterNotations(ByVal Top As String)
    Dim TopCat As String

    TopCat = "TOP " & Top


    con.Open()
    Cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT " & TopCat & " categorie, COUNT(Id) AS n FROM notations GROUP BY categorie ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC", con)
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()


    Using Cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT notations.* FROM notations INNER JOIN (SELECT " & TopCat & " categorie, COUNT(Id) AS n FROM notations GROUP BY categorie ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC) AS a ON notations.categorie = a.categorie", con)
        con.Open()
        Using Dad = New OleDbDataAdapter(Cmd)
            Dst.Clear()
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Dst.Tables()
            Dad.Fill(Dst, "notations")
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Dst.Tables(0)
        End Using
    End Using
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

The next thing I need some help with is how can I, in addition to how I filter already use the date as in (01-07-16) to get the most occurring between date1 and date2. If some one could give me a gentle push in the right direction that would be kind.

**UPDATE#1**

I have investigated the clause WHERE and BETWEEN, from the information I could getter from the internet. I came up with this code:

```
Private Sub FilterNotations(ByVal Top As String)
        Dim TopCat As String

        TopCat = "TOP " & Top


        con.Open()
        Cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT " & TopCat & " categorie, COUNT(Id) AS n FROM notations WHERE creation_date BETWEEN #7/2/16# AND #7/5/16# GROUP BY categorie ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC", con)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()


        Using Cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT notations.* FROM notations INNER JOIN (SELECT " & TopCat & " categorie, COUNT(Id) AS n FROM notations WHERE creation_date BETWEEN #7/2/16# AND #7/5/16# GROUP BY categorie ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC) AS a ON notations.categorie = a.categorie", con)
            con.Open()
            Using Dad = New OleDbDataAdapter(Cmd)
                Dst.Clear()
                DataGridView1.DataSource = Dst.Tables()
                Dad.Fill(Dst, "notations")
                DataGridView1.DataSource = Dst.Tables(0)
            End Using
        End Using
        con.Close()


    End Sub
```

The problem is that in my datagrid it doesn't show the result I was hoping for.
The SELECT TOP x function works great but it doesn't filter the with date.
could someone please give me a hint.

Kind regards Jordy

Comment: There is no filtering going on there at all. If you want to filter data using a SQL query then there must be a `WHERE` and/or `HAVING` clause.  You have neither so you are doing no filtering.  In order to filter by date, you add a `WHERE` clause with criteria relating to dates. I suggest that you do some research on SQL `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Sorry I meant sorting but what I need to do is Filter by date. I will investigate The Where clause.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - I have updated my original question to explain what I have changed in my first code, after investigating the WHERE and BETWEEN clause.

Answer (score 0):

As always I provide my own answer to my own question.

so I needed to put `WHERE creation_date BETWEEN #7/2/16# AND #7/5/16#` after `AS a ON notations.categorie = a.categorie`

Now it works as expected.

Thank you to jmcilhinney for providing the pieces I needed.